# How to get 'diff' on Windows TravisCI machines?

Tags: windows, travis-ci

Attempt was `choco install git -y`, but it does not seem to be available:

```
The command "diff -u <(echo -n) <(gofmt -d ./)" exited with 2.
diff: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
```

[Windows Travis Build](https://travis-ci.org/030/go-multipart/jobs/600458560)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `git` is installed it usually doesn't add the `diff` executable to the path because it would conflict with other versions of `diff` native to Windows, for example, the `Compare-Object` alias in PowerShell.

1. You can usually get around this by adding `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\` to the path which contains all of the UNIX ports of functionality such `diff`, `grep`, `awk`, `sed`.  You do have to be careful as some commands are used more commonly on Windows than others, the most common one is `find`.
2. A second option would be to fully qualify the call to `diff` by appending `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.